# How to fix NoReverseMatch 'user' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a website, and want to make a user login page. But I always get "NoReverseMatch at /users/login/ and  'user' is not a registered namespace" when I am on the login page.

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from . import views

app_name ='users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
         name='login'),
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p.Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'user:login' %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <botton name="sumbit">log in</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="next"
            value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

and base.html that login extends from

```
<p>
  <a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log </a> -
  <a href = "{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello, {{  user.username }}.
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
  {% endif %}

</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your app_name='users' and you're calling 'user' in the template. That's why you're getting that. Also you have an opened but not closed single quote on your template.